How do I toggle between a tabbed page and an untabbed page in angular?
I have a tab page that has a link on it. When the link is clicked, it goes to an untabbed details page. But there is a button on the details page that goes back to the tabbed page. The problem is, the tabbed page don't disappear when going to the details page (the tabbed page is covering the details page). How do i hide the tabbed page when i got to the details page, but show the show the tabbed page when i left the details page?

you can use Angular's routing capabilities along with conditional rendering to show or hide the tabbed page based on the current route.

Been trying to do that... Can't seem to get it to work... Changes to the variable in the component's  show/hide Boolean stop being recognized once you leave that component. Is there a away to tie into the native DOM Events of JavaScript?

turns out you were right. My issue wasn't that the variable were not being recognized. My issue was the fact of the fact that I had two different conditions in two different areas that was overriding each other.
